# How to delete the line after a search pattern, globally with vi?

Tags: linux, vi

Assume I have a big file, ~1k lines, and I need to **delete the line after** some pattern, lets call it: `somePatern`.

Conditions:

- cannot be done by hand (no searching -- `/somePattern`, and/or manually moving down one line and deleting).
- preferably a single liner.
- line after the line that contains the pattern has to be gone (no empty line)
- has to be UNIX compatible (I use Debian but need it for UNIX -- great if works on both)

Also if anyone has a link to a site where I can learn this and more regex stuff that be awesome! (But not a beginners type of tut, I have that down, courtesy of `vimtutor` and others.)

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but still I think it can be useful: http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`g/somepattern/+d`

In the following example baz was removed. (I only verified with Vim though.)

```
foo     
bar 
somepattern 
baz 
someotherpattern
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://vimregex.com/) in section 3.2 "Range of Operation, Line Addressing and Marks".
It seems that Vim commands can accept a line range in front of them. By specifying the line range you restrict the command execution to this particular part of text only.

For example:

`/pattern[/]` the next line where text "pattern" matches

`?pattern[?]` the previous line where text "pattern" matches